# Can I prevent node_modules bundled with webpack from using window.postMessage?

Tags: security, webpack, electron, node-modules

For security reasons, I need to disallow 3rd party modules which are included in my bundle by webpack from using `window.postMessage` to communicate with other processes in my Electron app.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

A standard trick could help here: simply move the method to another variable on window, like this maybe:

```
window._postMessage = window.postMessage;
window.postMessage = () => {};
```

Run this first on your render script or with a `<script>` tag on your html and plugins that would use that can't send events anymore (in fact, they don't crash but never get a response).

Edit

If you want to make sure that only authorized user can use it, something like this could work:

```
function createSecurePostMessage() {
  const _postMessage = window.postMessage;

  return {
    get() {return function(...args) {
      if (isAuthorized(...args) {
         _postMessage(...args);
      }
    }
  }
}
window.postMessage = createSecurePostMessage().get();
```

Now the original postMessage is inside the function and inaccessible and you can implement a method, for example, that checks if a certain message can be sent. If someone calls create again, then the secured postMethod will just be 'secured' again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that’s not as secure as I would like it. My code is open source. A determined hacker could see the new name and ship code that uses the new name. Or they could enumerate all the methods on ‘window’ and some how test if they were postMessage

Comment: If you don't need the postMessage method, you can simply remove it: `delete window.postMessage`.

Comment: But I do need it 

Comment: @M.K.Safi - check if my edit helps you a bit more :)

Comment: I don't think this will work because there are messages that I want only my code to be able to send. So I would whitelist that message in `isAuthorized`, but then the 3rd party malicious code would also be able to send the same message.

Comment: This 'isAuthorized' is just a placeholder for your secure method. The edit was about hiding the postMessage method so that no one can invoke it directly anymore. You could use some tokens, sign it cryptographically based on some enveironment variables, or whatever. That's finally up to you :)

Comment: I don't understand how this helps. You're modifying `postMessage` to make it check for pre-authorization. The malicious code could still invoke `window.postMessage` while pretending to be legitimate code. `isAuthorized` seems to be the main mechanism of protection, which as I explained in the previous comment, wouldn't work.

Comment: I'm not modifying it. It's a replacement. Monkey patching. That malicous code can call *a*  postMessage method, which is *your* implementation and so *you* have full control whether you let that message pass or not. It is *not* possible to configure the system in a way that it allows function execution for some modules but not for others. If you want a guard, you'll have to implement that and this is one idea,

Comment: "you have full control whether you let that message pass or not" I don't know based on what I would decide to let the message pass or not. A token (nonce) or a private key that is available to my code would also be available (directly or indirectly) to node_modules code. So this is not very secure. Also, if `isAuthorized` is the gatekeeper then I could put it on the receiving end of the postMessage communication. I wouldn't need to monkey patch `postMessage` for that.

Comment: I don't really see the point of defensively trying to avoid libraries accessing the code. you should check the libraries before bundling them if you care so much about something like this.

Just by moving the function to something else would eliminate the option of using it by accident. You said it is open source and a malicious person could change it, but why change that on a library? If it were me I'll download the code and change that, recompile and serve it.

if you want security, then you need authentication, but it depends a lot on your project on how to achieve that.

Comment: @Willyfrog I can't be 100% sure that all the libraries and all of their sub-dependencies are safe. My project is Bitcoin-related. A vulnerability like this could result in irreversible financial loss. My concern is not a malicious user, but a malicious library author whose code ends-up being included in my Electron app.

Comment: a library shouldn't end up in your code out of nowhere, you need to figure out which part of the whole chain is the one that might hurt you and fix that one.
By your comment I'd say, create your own npm-registry and only push trusted libraries there, otherwise your other option is to not use any libraries.